# how to pull items from an element in an array using ksh93?

Tags: arrays, linux, ksh

I have the following file

```
acc1:server1:server2:acc1234:blah:blah
acc2:server1:server5:acc4321:blah:blah
acc3:server1:server3:acc2222:blah:blah
```

Each line of the above file is an element in an array. I only need to get the first three items so `accX:serverX:serverX`.

How can I pull out only the first three items of each element without the ":" using ksh93?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for you:

```
$ set -A myarr acc1:server1:server2:acc1234:blah:blah acc2:server1:server5:acc4321:blah:blah acc3:server1:server3:acc2222:blah:blah

$ $ for ele in ${myarr[@]}; do ele=${ele%:*:*:*}; echo ${ele//:/ }; done
acc1 server1 server2
acc2 server1 server5
acc3 server1 server3
```

Comment: ${ele%:*:*:*}; returns acc1 acc2 acc3 acc4. It does not return the server information. Any ideas? thanks.

Comment: @user1718586 Can you please update your question by running the above command and showing exactly the output you are getting. I am not sure how you array is being constructed.

Comment: I had a typo. This does work. Is it possible to pull out the second item so server1 for all 3 elements? thanks.

Comment: Actually this should suffice `for ele in ${myarr[@]}; do ele=${ele#*:}; echo ${ele%%:*}; done` since there is no : to remove you can ignore the last part. Don't forget to mark the answer :)

Comment: Hey JS. One more thing. Is it possibel to do something like mailacc=${myarray[0,1] where 0 is the element and 1 is the 1st item? So mailacc=${myarray[2,1] would be equal to acc3 in the above example. I want to assign a variable for each item in an element. Thanks.

Comment: Multidimensional arrays are not supported. You can post another question to see if someone can suggest a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

```
     #!/bin/ksh

     file=~/kshinput.txt
     index=0

     while read line
     do
            myarray[$index]=${line%:*:*:*}
            ((index=index+1))
     done <"$file"


     for i in {0..$index}
     do
            echo "$i: ${myarray[$i]}"
     done
```